# Hibernate question

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I getting an error when running my program. the error is: org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
The driver is there...I am not sure what it causing this. Any suggestions?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrar</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<mapping resource="com/ths/entity/Course.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/ths/entity/Student.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/ths/entity/Enrollment.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Post your Hibernate config. Do you have the driver referenced in the classpath? We need more information to help you.

Comment: Where is the mysql driver? Is it on the classpath where it can be found?

Comment: I posted my hibernate config....i am using netbeans and I am pretty sure it is the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was causing this. I was trying this on my work computer. I tried it at home and it worked fine. Must just be a setting.

Answer (score 1):

> The driver is there...I am not sure what it causing this.

The driver is *not* there. The error is simple: the Java VM couldn't find your driver. So, double-check the classpath. If you are deploying a web-application, make sure your driver is in the server's lib, and not in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1):

You may have that jar in project but class loader is unable to find that as class loader does not check each and every folder of project. If it is a web application then you need to put jar file in WEB-INF/LIB.

If it is a standalone application then you need to add jar file in build path.

you can check class path during run time to see whether folder (where jar exist) is considered in class path or not.